# is it possible to create a hash map where each value is a method that acts differently on an object

Tags: java, hashmap, time-complexity, state

**Problem**

I want to know if this is possible if I could create a `State machine` that would contain all the methods and the Values of `MethodById` would be stated in the machine.

P.S. this is my first question ever on here. If I do it wrong I'm sorry but that is why.

---

**Description (TL;DR)**

I'm trying to cross reference data about Sales representatives. Each rep has *territories* specified by ***zip-codes***.

One dataset has the reps, their territories and their company. 
Another data set has their names, phone number and email.

I made a Sales-rep class that takes from the first data-set and needs to be updated with the second data-set. 
I also need the Sales-reps to be put in a look-up table (I used a **hashmap** for this) of `<key: zip code, value: Sales-rep object>`.

What I want is for each Sales-rep object to having an `ID` that is standard across all my datasets. I can't use the data I'm provided with because it comes from many different sources and its impossible to standardize any data field.

Names, for example, are listed so many different ways it would be impossible to reconcile them and use that as an `ID`.

If I can get an `ID` like this (something like an SSN but less sensitive) then I want to try what my question is about.

I want to iterate through all the elements in my `<key: zip code, value: Sales-rep object>` **hashmap**, we will call it `RepsByZipCode`. When I iterate through each *Salesrep object* I want to get an `ID` that I can use in a different hashmap called `MethodById` `<key: ID, value: a method run on the Object with this ID>`.

I want it to run a different method for ***each key*** on the Object with the matching key (AKA the ID). The point is to run a different method on each different object in linear time so that by the end of the for loop, each object in `RepsByZipCode` will have some method run on it that can update information (thus completing the cross-referencing).

This also makes the code very extendable because I can change the method for each key if I want to update things differently. Ex:

```
//SalesRep Object Constructor:
SalesRep(String name, String email, ..., String Id)

Map<String zipcode, Salesrep rep> RepsByZipCode = new HashMap<>{}
//code fills in the above with the first dataset
Map<String ID, ??? method> MethodById = new HashMap<>{}
//code fills in the above with the second dataset

for(String ZipKey:RepsByZipCode){
    Salesrep Rep = RepsByZipCode.get(ZipKey);
    Rep.getId = ID;
    MethodById.get(ID);
    //each time this runs, one entry in RepsByZipCode is updated with one 
    //method from MethodById.
//after this for loop, all of RepsByZipCode has been updated in linear time
```

Comment: the way I see it is you can create a string and store your methods name in it and then the moment you use it you need to create it in method and then pass your arguments to it.

Comment: Ok? can you show me how I would use a String containing a method name to actually run that method? I'm confused because to me that would seem like I would just be storing a string. I don't know how you would actually run the method when you needed it.

Comment: you have the function name you can parse the name in method by appending "()" and then pass the arguments

Comment: Don't store a string. Store an instance of Consumer<Something> or Function<Something>.

Comment: @Lokesh no, you can't do that in Java.

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: I'm sorry if I worded it wrong in the title, I just couldn't think of any other way to phrase it. If you have any title suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put these methods into different classes that implement a common interface, and store an instance of each class in your map. If you're using at least Java 8 and your methods are simple enough, you could use [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to avoid some boilerplate.

Comment: Or method references.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid making separate classes for each of these because really I want methods that update information on Sales-Rep objects based on a data-set that I'm cross referencing. Like for example, I want to update the Object with Id = 1 to have the Name "bob" So I would want the method to be stuff like Object.setname("bob"). I'd also like to be able to find Id matches between the data-sets and update class attributes accordingly. Can you show me an example of the lambdas you mean? I've used them before a lot but my memory in school is toast.

Comment: You'd be passing those other objects into these methods anyways, they'd still be parameters if the methods were part of a class.

Comment: Frankly I don't understand what you mean. If I made a class for each method and stored it in the <id, method> hash-map wouldn't I just be storing a class object with one method inside it? I don't understand how you could "store" a lambda expression Although I think you're right about using them because that is basically what I need, a functional interface thats short in code. I just don't understand the "storing in a hash-map part" because Its like the difference between a noun and a verb to me. I can store nouns but I can't store a verb.

Comment: Yes, for each different behaviour you'd have a different class implementing, for example, some `IdHandler` interface with a `handleId()` method. You'd then have a `Map<String, IdHandler>` which you could then use like `IdHandler handler = myMap.get(id); handler.handleId(id, otherData)`. Similarly lambdas are in a sense objects which implement some [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html). This is their object type for the purposes of things like variables and maps.